# how can i keep my jvm from exiting while netty client connection is open?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, netty

I have an API which uses netty to open client connection to a tcp server. The server may send data to the client at any time. I'm facing the following scenario:

1. Client connects to server
2. Sends data to server
3. Disconnects and the JVM exist (not sure happens first)

This is what I expect:

1. Client connects to server
2. Sends data to server
3. Client simply keeps the connections open, waiting to receive data or for the user of client API to send data.

This is an outline of my connection method (obviously there is a much larger API around it):

```

```
public FIXClient connect(String host, int port) throws Throwable {
    ...
    ChannelPipeline pipe = org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.pipeline(...);

    ChannelFactory factory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);
    bootstrap.setPipeline(pipe);

    bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);

    ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

    //forcing the connect call to block
    //don't want clients to deal with async connect calls
    future.awaitUninterruptibly();

    if(future.isSuccess()){
        this.channel = future.getChannel();
        //channel.getCloseFuture();//TODO notifies whenever channel closes
    }
    else{
        throw future.getCause();//wrap this in a more specific exception
    }

    return this;
}
```

```

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing todo with netty... You need to make sure your "main" method will not exist if you call it from there. Otherwise it the job of the container..

Comment: In order to test my client code, I used "System.in.read();" to keep my program from ending. However, I found that messages I wrote to netty channel didn't actually get delivered to the server until the jvm moved beyond that line. That's why I'm trying to find the 'standard' way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways you can do this, but one thing I have observed, is that with this code:

```
ChannelFactory factory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
```

... if you make a successful connection, your JVM will not shutdown of it's own accord for some time until you force it (like a kill) or you call a [releaseExternalResources()](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory.html#releaseExternalResources%28%29) on your channel factory. This is because:

- The threads created by [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) are **nonDaemon** threads.
- At least 1 thread would be created once you submit your connection request.
- The cached thread pool threads have a keep alive time of 60 seconds, meaning they don't go away until they've been idle for 60 seconds, so that would be 60 seconds *after* your connect and send (assuming that they both completed).

So I'm not sure if you're diagnosing the issue correctly. Having said that, I recommend you handle the task this this way:

1. Once you boot in your **main** method (in the **main** thread)
2. Now launch *all* your actual useful work in new threads.
3. Once the useful threads have been launched, in the **main** thread, call [Thread.currentThread().join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). Since **main** is always non-dameon, you have made sure the JVM will not shutdown until you're good and ready.
4. At some point, unless you *want* to **kill -9** the JVM as a shutdown strategy, you will want a controlled shutdown, so you can [add a shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to shutdown Netty and then interrupt the **main** thread.

I hope that's helpful.